# Questions on Generalized Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Theorem:

$V_{(\lambda)}$ = {$ v \in V | f^k_{\lambda} (v) = 0$ for some $k \geq 1 $}

(i)$V_{(\lambda)}$ is an $f_\mu$-invariant subspace for every $\lambda$ and $\mu$ in $\mathbb{F}$.

(ii)$f_{\mu_{|V_{\lambda}}}$ is injective if $\mu \neq \lambda$

(iii)Let $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, ... \lambda_s$ be distinct elements of $\mathbb{F}$. Let $v_r \in V_{(\lambda_{r})} $ and suppose $v_1 + v_2 + ... + v_s$ = 0. Then $v_1 = v_2 = ... = v_s = 0$.

The proof of (ii) is given as follows:

Assume $\mu \neq \lambda$. Let $v\in V_{(\lambda)}$ be a non zero vector satisfying $f_\mu (v) = 0$. Let k be the minimal positive integer l such that $f^{l}_{\lambda} (v) = 0$. Then k is finite because $v \in V_{(\lambda)}$, and $w = f^{k-1}_{\lambda} (v) \neq 0$ because k is minimal. Moreover, $f_\lambda (w) = f^k_{\lambda} (v) = 0$, so $w \in V_\lambda$. Hence, $f_\mu (w) = (\lambda - \mu) w$, wherefore

$$ 0 \neq (\lambda - \mu) w = f_\mu (w) = f_\mu (f^{k-1}_\lambda (v)) = f^{k-1}_\lambda (f_\mu (v) ) = f^{k-1}_\lambda (0) = 0 $$

which is a contradiction. We conclude that $f_{\mu_{|V_{\lambda}}}$ has a kernel {0}; hence, it is injective.

Here, $f_{\mu_{|V_{\lambda}}}$ is the restriction of $f_\mu$ to the domain of $V_{\lambda}$.

There are a few things that I don't understand:

1)Why we will be able to choose nonzero vector from $v\in V_{(\lambda)}$ satisfying $f_\mu (v) = 0$?

2)Why $w \in V_\lambda$ and why $f_\mu (w) = (\lambda - \mu) w$?

Answer (score 0):

1) We want to prove that there is no $v\in V_{(\lambda)}$, $v\neq 0$ such that $f_{\mu}(v)=0$, but this proof is by contradiction, thus we assume the opposite.

2) Since you didn't explain the meaning of $f_{\lambda}$, I am assuming that $f_{\lambda}=f-\lambda Id$. Thus, $f_{\lambda}(w)=0$ means $f(w)=\lambda w$ and $f_{\mu}(w)= f(w)-\mu w=(\lambda-\mu)w$

Comment: for 2), should w be $\in V_(\lambda)$ instead? is it a typo in my note?

Comment: Notice that $w\in V_{(\lambda)}$ because $f_{\lambda}(w)=0$. See the definition of $V_{(\lambda)}$.